# How is Java 9 (going to be) different from Java 8?

Tags: java

What are the key points to be kept in mind while developing a project using Java 9 as compared to Java 8?

Comment: backwards compatibility.

Comment: read http://blog.takipi.com/java-9-the-ultimate-feature-list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive source of information on what it *likely* to be in Java 9 is the JDK 9 project page:

- http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/

Of course, we cannot say for sure what will be in Java 9 until much closer to the actual release date.  As the project says:

> "The goal of this Project is to produce an open-source reference implementation of the Java SE 9 Platform, *to be defined by a forthcoming JSR in the Java Community Process.*"

The implication of the above (and past history) is that we know for sure until the Java 9 release candidate is available.

---

> What are the key points to be kept in mind while developing a project using Java 9 as compared to Java 8?

There are one or two things that have been deprecated in Java 8 and are due to be withdrawn in Java 9.  (For example using `_` as an identifier will be a compilation error from Java 9 onwards.)  So one "key point" is to pay attention to any deprecation warnings.

But you can also expect the goal of maximal backwards compatibility to be treated as paramount.  Java 8 (and 7, 6, 5, etc) code should continue to work on Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of features are introduced in java 9 like -

1. Project Jigsaw – Modular Source Code
2. Lightweight JSON API
3. Process API updates
4. Segmented Code Cache
5. Money and Currency API
   and a lot more features are introduced.

Personally I like `Jigsaw` concept the most

**Source** - http://www.codingeek.com/java/java-9-top-5-features-release-information/